# How to use the tuples created in one python script to another?

Tags: python, tuples

Suppose I have a tuple of tuples I created say `a = ((2,2),(5,5),(6,2))`
in my current python script `A.py`. I want to import these tuple of tuples into another python script `B.py`. Writing into a text file requires it to a be string but I want to export `a` defined in `A.py` as it is. How do I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say `file1.py` contains:

```
tup = (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Then in `file2.py` use:

```
from file1 import tup
print(tup)
```

(This assumes that `file1.py` and `file2.py` are in the same folder)